# Is there a general solution to this problem?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Assuming $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1, \beta_2$ are both boundary parameters and variables.

For all $x_1, x_2$, we have $x_1 \in [\alpha_1, \beta_1]$ and $x_2 \in [\alpha_2, \beta_2]$.

Also, $x_1, x_2$ are constrained by additional inequalities like $0.5 \leq x_1 + x_2 \leq 1$.

How to get the maximum intervals between $\alpha$ and $\beta$

$$max \ \ (\beta_1 - \alpha_1) + (\beta_2 - \alpha_2)\\ s.t. \forall x_1 \in [\alpha_1, \beta_1]\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x_2 \in [\alpha_2, \beta_2] \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.5 \leq x_1 + x_2 \leq 1 \\\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  0 \leq \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2 \leq 1$$

I'm not sure if the problem can be transfer a general robust optimization problem

Comment: Take $\alpha_i = 0$ and $\beta_i =1$, yielding maximum $1 - 0 + 1 - 0 =2$.

Comment: But if $x_i = 1$, $x_1 + x_2$ will be 2 @RobPratt

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood your $\forall$ conditions.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define square $S=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, quadrilateral $Q=\{(x_1,x_2)\in S: 0.5 \le x_1 + x_2 \le 1\}$, and rectangle $R=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\times[\alpha_2,\beta_2]$.  You want to find $\alpha_i,\beta_i \in S$ to maximize the semiperimeter $\sum_{i=1}^2 (\beta_i-\alpha_i)$ of $R$ subject to $R \subset Q$.  By convexity, $R \subset Q$ if and only if all four corners of $R$ are in $Q$.  You can solve the problem via linear programming: maximize the linear function $\sum_{i=1}^2 (\beta_i-\alpha_i)$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
0.5 \le \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 &\le 1 \\
0.5 \le \alpha_1 + \beta_2 &\le 1 \\
0.5 \le \beta_1 + \alpha_2 &\le 1 \\
0.5 \le \beta_1 + \beta_2 &\le 1 \\
\alpha_i &\ge 0 \\
\beta_i &\ge 0
\end{align}

But there is also a simple geometric argument.  From a [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vsxfmyjmc9) of $Q$, it is clear that you want the lower left corner $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ to be on the bottom border and the upper right corner $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$ to be on the top border:
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 &= 0.5 \tag1\label1\\
\beta_1 + \beta_2 &= 1 \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Now subtracting \eqref{1} from \eqref{2} yields maximum semiperimeter $0.5$.

Comment: If $i = 1000$, we need $C(2000, 1000)$ linear constraints corresponding $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to formulate $0.5 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{1000} x_i \leq 1$. Is that right?

Comment: If we have N random variables and M additional constraints, M * C(2 * N, N) is too large for the practical problem.

Comment: In $N$ dimensions, the polyhedron $[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\times\dots\times[\alpha_N,\beta_N]$ has $2^N$ vertices.  Your question contained only one additional constraint on $x$. What are your $M$ additional constraints?